# Cómo detectar si una conexión es Telnet en eventos OnConnect y OnDisconnect de TIdTCPServer Delphi

Tags: delphi, tcpip, indy

En un programa Delphi, se tiene un componente TCP server (TIdTCPServer) escuchando. Para efectos de monitoreo es necesario generar un alerta cuando se presente una conexión o una desconexión Telnet.

Cómo puedo precisar si una conexión es Telnet en los eventos OnConnect y OnDisconnect?

```
procedure TComponent.XMLTCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin

end;

procedure TComponent.XMLTCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin

end;
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué otros tipos de conexiones recibes en ese mismo puerto? Es decir, ¿no todas son Telnet? Pregunto porque no termino de comprender qué es lo que quieres lograr con esto. Un saludo.

Comment: Las conexiones se realizan desde clientes TCP y se recibe mensajería transaccional, pero un servicio de un balanceador verifica cada determinado tiempo si la conexión esta disponible y lo hace con una conexión Telnet.
Gracias jachguate.

Comment: En la conexión, no hay nada que indique el "tipo de cliente". No recuerdo con exactitud en el caso de Telnet, si hay la posibilidad de algún tipo de _diálogo_ inicial, por ejemplo, para negociar el tipo de terminal, sospecho que no. ¿Para qué necesitas hacer la diferencia entre un cliente y otro? Pregunto porque quizás hay otras alternativas.

Comment: Por cada conexión de un cliente se registran en una base de datos las conexiones y las desconexiones. Y debo excluir las Telnet porque no son clientes reales.

Comment: Si conoces la IP del balanceador, podrías entonces discriminar las conexiones que vengan de esa IP. De otra forma, tendrías que esperar a que comience la comunicación para identificar si se trata de uno u otro.